# How to load data from mysql with fadein one by one loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

How to load data from mysql with fadein one by one loop ?

OK, i will load image from mysql total 40 image

Then i want to display

```
<li class="img" style=" list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px; ">
    <img src="<?PHP echo $img_products[0]; ?>"/>
</li>
```

with `fadein` and `delay 0.5 sec.` And then display

```
<li class="img" style=" list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px; ">
    <img src="<?PHP echo $img_products[1]; ?>"/>
</li>
```

with `fadein` and `delay 0.5 sec.` And then display

```
<li class="img" style=" list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px; ">
    <img src="<?PHP echo $img_products[2]; ?>"/>
</li>
```

with `fadein` and `delay 0.5 sec.` And then display

```
<li class="img" style=" list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px; ">
    <img src="<?PHP echo $img_products[3]; ?>"/>
</li>
```

until display to

```
<li class="img" style=" list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px; ">
    <img src="<?PHP echo $img_products[39]; ?>"/>
</li>
```

i try to using `loop for PHP` to do that  , but not work, How an i do that ?

```
<?PHP 
for($i=0;$i<40;$i++)
{
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE data_type = '$strID' order by id desc Limit $i,1 ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
    $objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
    $img_products[$i] = $objResult["img_path"];
}


for($i=0;$i<40;$i++)
{
<li class="img" style=" list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px; ">
    <img src="<?PHP echo $img_products[$i]; ?>"/>
</li>
}
?>
```

Comment: You will probably want to use a javascript library like jQuery. That will probably be the nicest execution of a looped fade in

Comment: Basically, you want javascript/jquery slideshow? There are really many nice options....

Comment: Agree, use a jquery slideshow. Side note: doing 40 queries to fetch 40 images is really inefficient. Can you do one query with limit 40 and then make the <li>s in the while loop?

Comment: Do you want the previous image to fade out, so you only ever see one at a time, or do you want keep them visible, so you end up with all 40 images displayed (after 20 seconds)?

Comment: no, all previous image are still.

Comment: Ok, and are you able to use jQuery, or are you stuck with plain javascript?

Comment: now, i try every way that i know, But i can not do that , and i no ideas about jquery , Could you please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to 1st output the html for all 40 images in php. Making 40 queries is just illogical, so i have changed that to make 1 query with a limit of 40 results.

```
<?php
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE data_type = '$strID' order by id desc Limit 40";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)):?>

    <li class="img" style="display:none; list-style: none; float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px; ">
        <img src="<?php echo $row["img_path"]; ?>"/>
    </li>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Also note that the `<li>` tags are hidden with css using `display:none;`.
Then using javascript (in this case with jquery) you can loop through all the li tags, and set a timer to show them. The loop works by increasing the timout by 500 miliseconds per item:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('li.img').each(function(index){
        $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(400);
    });
});
</script>
```

Obligatory note: mysql_* functions are depreciated. You should instead use mysqli_* or pdo instead